# White (Lavan) & Blue (Tcheiles) - blue Tzitzis

Tags: halacha, minhag, tzitzis, techeles

There are some people that wear Tcheiles - blue Tzitzis. What is the reason that the majority of Klal Yisroel still does not wear it if the Tcheilas has been rediscovered?