# How did the mesorah for techeles get lost?

Tags: history, tzitzis, mesorah-tradition, techeles

It seems odd that something like the tradition for techeles could have been lost. It seems unlikely that Jews just stopped using techeles at some point and then immediately forgot. Are there no records of how the dye was made?

Comment: See the Tshuva of the Satmar Rebbe

Comment: how and where can I find this?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20289&st=&pgnum=196

Comment: My understanding is that it was out of fashion because it was too expensive. Once you can't afford it, no one makes it, and the memory gets lost ...

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38503/5323

Comment: @yishai teffilin were cheaper

Comment: @sam, yes, because they are made from readily available materials. Techeiles is more similar to Lulav and Esrog, which was indeed in great danger of being lost among Ashkenazim. BTW, that isn't intended to contradict the reason of the דברי יאול - why the Mitzvah doesn't apply is a different question than how it happened that the Mesorah was lost. Put it this way, I don't think he means to say that the Chachamim after the Churban Bais said stop making Techeiles. Rather Hashgacha Pratis arranged it because the Mitzvah isn't really applicable.

Comment: How do you explain the techeles of Mordichai acc to the Divrei Yoel,it suddenly came back?

Comment: @sam, I only read a couple of paragraphs of the דברי יואל looking for what you were referring to. If you could point me to exactly what you are thinking of, I'll take a look.

Comment: Its the next page it starts ubyimaei Purim...

Comment: The only way there would be no records is if it was a super secret animal that only Jews knew how to use and did so secretly. If it was a known expensive dye source (which there's no reason to think it isn't given its presence in gentile settings, like Achashverosh's court (8:15) or Hiram of Tyre (Chron 2:26)) then of course there are records and there's no secret. The latter position is taken by those who wear Murex Trunculus based dye on their strings since that was the known blue dye source of the ancient Mediterranean and there's no doubts how to make it.

Comment: Great sources here: https://www.techeiles.org/library/ https://www.techeiles.org/harav-meir-halevi-hellman-levush-haaron/ לבוש הארון בירור בענין כשרות חלזון המורקס לקיום מצות תכלת An examination of the Kashrus of the Murex snail for Techeiles

Answer (score 2):

I watched in this torah live video (https://torahlive.com/courses/tzitzis/) that in the times of the Romans they threatened to put in jail or kill anyone making or transporting techeiles because they wanted it for royal use only. It also says in [Menachos (.מג)](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.43a?lang=bi) that ר'אחאי had techeiles, and he passed away in the year 510ce. Then in [Midrash Tanchuma](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Sh%27lach.15.1?vhe=Midrash_Tanchuma_--_Torat_Emet&lang=he) it laments the loss of techeiles so we see that techeiles was lost sometime between the years 510 and 800.

Answer (score 1):

It was  still around in the fifth century because the Gemorah  (Menochos 43A) when discussing how to make Techelis mentions Rav Achai having  Techilis sent to him.

It is unclear when and how Techlis got lost but apparently the Roman government did not allow it to be worn because the Gemara (Sanhedrin 12A) makes reference to an unsuccessful attempt to smuggle techeles from Eretz Yisroel to Bavel.  The  smugglers were almost killed.

Even in the best of times it wasn't easy to obtain. The fish it comes from only surfaced once in seventy years. Presumably as time went on it became more and more difficult to obtain until it became lost altogether.