# Why don't we wear techeilet

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, techeles

Why don't we apply the rule of
ספק דאורייתא לחומרה to techeilet?
If there are rabbanim who hold it is the real techelet, and there is compelling evidence that we now know what techeilet is, why doesn't that create enough of a safek for us to be stringent and fulfill this mizva?

Comment: Also related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12592/compelling-arguments-to-support-techelet

Comment: As to this specific point -- that rule only applies if being "machmir" gets you out of the safek! If I'm not sure if I benched at 6pm, and now I bench at 6:15pm, I have definitely benched in the past hour. If I'm not sure if murex is techeles, and now I wear murex ... am I sure I have worn techeles?

Comment: @Shalom if it is now dusk and I haven't blown shofar, I should blow shofar even though I won't know afterwards if I fulfilled the mitzva or not

Comment: @Dov the part that mentions my question is an aside in the comments. I don't believe it's a dupe

Comment: So you're more specifically asking why don't we apply suffik doraisa lechumrah to techeiles. Are you asking the same way the Radziner was asking about why people weren't convinced of his techeiles, or more specifically to the Murex?

Comment: @robev yes that is my question. I'm not of the specifics though. Whichever is more compelling

Comment: I feel like this question is subsumed in the other question though. A good answer to that question will answer this one.