# Evidence for murex being techelet

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, techeles, chazal, orach-chaim

As a disclaimer, the Sugyot regarding Techelet are not something I have in depth researched but I am in the camp that it has been found from murex. My question is, what evidence exists in Talmud or Chazal for  the pro murex opinion as proofs?

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/itm/394876328368

Comment: There are dozens if not hundreds of articles about this all over the internet. What did you find lacking?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12592

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This shiur series](https://kosherjava.com/mordechai/) by R' Mordechai Hershfeld presents both sides of the murex techeiles debate, as well as discussing the Radziner cuttlefish history. I'll just give the caveat that he himself is anti-murex, although that only really comes out in the later shiurim.