Why are we allowed to wear tzitzis nowadays?
The Torah explicitly tells us that when we wear a (four) cornered garment it needs tzitzis and Tcheles.
״ועשו להם ציצית על כנפי בגדיהם לדרותם ונתנו על ציצית הכנף פתיל תכלת״ (במדבר ט״ו:ל״ג)
Since today we are uncertain about what Tcheles is, how are we allowed to wear tzitzis?

Closely related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17509/

Seems a duplicate of that question, no, @Fred ?

@msh210 Likely, although this one seems to focus on direct interpretation of the pesukim.

Rambam mishnah Torah sefer ahava tzitzis ch. 1
Here the Rambam explains the mitvah tzitzis and techeles can be fulfilled independently of each other. If one does not have techeles then the white strings can be worn alone to fulfill that mitzvah. Similarly if one had both in their tzitzis but the white stings were somehow torn off so that only techeles remained you would still be permitted to wear them to fulfill the mitzvah of tzitzis.

The mishna in menachot (38a) states that not wearing  techelet does not hold back the mitzvah, and one who wears tzitsit without techelet will still fulfill  the mitzvah of tzitit, although he will lack the techelet aspect of the mitzvah. Therefore those who do not wear techelet still fulfill the mitzvah of tzitsit which is why they wear tzitsit.

Kli chemda says in mitzvas tzitzis is lidoros (for all generations)and ticheles isnt ldoros (for generations, since it is destined to be lost)(based of drasha) therefore the aseh is more chashuv and it pushes off aseh of (not wearing) ticheles. Rav perlow says similar, that mitzvas tzitzis is more chashuv than ticheles, so it pushes it off.
But according to the Mordechai that holds if one cant put on strings he doesnt have to take off beged since he's ones(accident) the question doesn't start.
